# I want to modify setup, to also keep the serial USB port opens so I can send strings via a Raspberry Pi

Tags: serial, shields, usb, eeprom

I am trying to modify the original code from these guys GRA & AFCH, who have made an Arduino Sketch Program that runs a Arduino powered Nixie Clock.

Here is the link to their Firmware file:[NixieClockShieldNCS314.ino](https://github.com/afch/NixeTubesShieldNCS314/raw/master/NixieClockShieldNCS314.ino)

Here is the specific part I want to modify.

```cpp
void setup() 
{
  digitalWrite(DHVpin, LOW);    // off MAX1771 Driver  Hight Voltage(DHV) 110-220V

  Wire.begin();
  //setRTCDateTime(23,40,00,25,7,15,1);

  Serial.begin(115200);

    if (EEPROM.read(HourFormatEEPROMAddress)!=12) value[hModeValueIndex]=24; else value[hModeValueIndex]=12;
    if (EEPROM.read(RGBLEDsEEPROMAddress)!=0) RGBLedsOn=true; else RGBLedsOn=false;
    if (EEPROM.read(AlarmTimeEEPROMAddress)==255) value[AlarmHourIndex]=0; else value[AlarmHourIndex]=EEPROM.read(AlarmTimeEEPROMAddress);
    if (EEPROM.read(AlarmTimeEEPROMAddress+1)==255) value[AlarmMinuteIndex]=0; else value[AlarmMinuteIndex]=EEPROM.read(AlarmTimeEEPROMAddress+1);
    if (EEPROM.read(AlarmTimeEEPROMAddress+2)==255) value[AlarmSecondIndex]=0; else value[AlarmSecondIndex]=EEPROM.read(AlarmTimeEEPROMAddress+2);
    if (EEPROM.read(AlarmArmedEEPROMAddress)==255) value[Alarm01]=0; else value[Alarm01]=EEPROM.read(AlarmArmedEEPROMAddress);
    if (EEPROM.read(LEDsLockEEPROMAddress)==255) LEDsLock=false; else LEDsLock=EEPROM.read(LEDsLockEEPROMAddress);
    Serial.print("led lock=");
    Serial.println(LEDsLock);

  pinMode(RedLedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(GreenLedPin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BlueLedPin, OUTPUT);

  tone1.begin(pinBuzzer);
  song=parseSong(song);

  pinMode(LEpin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DHVpin, OUTPUT);

 // SPI setup

  SPI.begin(); // 
  SPI.setDataMode (SPI_MODE3); // Mode 3 SPI
  SPI.setClockDivider(SPI_CLOCK_DIV128); // SCK = 16MHz/128= 125kHz



  //buttons pins inits
  pinMode(pinSet,  INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(pinUp,  INPUT_PULLUP);
  pinMode(pinDown,  INPUT_PULLUP);
  ////////////////////////////
  pinMode(pinBuzzer, OUTPUT);

  //buttons objects inits
  setButton.debounceTime   = 20;   // Debounce timer in ms
  setButton.multiclickTime = 30;  // Time limit for multi clicks
  setButton.longClickTime  = 2000; // time until "held-down clicks" register

  upButton.debounceTime   = 20;   // Debounce timer in ms
  upButton.multiclickTime = 30;  // Time limit for multi clicks
  upButton.longClickTime  = 2000; // time until "held-down clicks" register

  downButton.debounceTime   = 20;   // Debounce timer in ms
  downButton.multiclickTime = 30;  // Time limit for multi clicks
  downButton.longClickTime  = 2000; // time until "held-down clicks" register

  //
  //digitalWrite(DHVpin, HIGH); // on MAX1771 Driver  Hight Voltage(DHV) 110-220V
  //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  doTest();
  //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
  if (LEDsLock==1)
    {
      setLEDsFromEEPROM();
    }
  getRTCTime();
  setTime(RTC_hours, RTC_minutes, RTC_seconds, RTC_day, RTC_month, RTC_year);
  digitalWrite(DHVpin, LOW); // off MAX1771 Driver  Hight Voltage(DHV) 110-220V
  setRTCDateTime(RTC_hours,RTC_minutes,RTC_seconds,RTC_day,RTC_month,RTC_year,1); //записываем только что считанное время в RTC чтобы запустить новую микросхему
  digitalWrite(DHVpin, HIGH); // on MAX1771 Driver  Hight Voltage(DHV) 110-220V    
  //p=song;
}
```

Now, I need to be able to constantly access the standard Serial USB to be able to receive a string from my Raspbery Pi. I was thinking of adding the following after their code in void setup()

```cpp
Serial.begin(9600);
```

Now I doubt this alone could let me constantly listen to input from Serial USB. But how can I make the code not conflict with the EEPROM.read() commands (I believe this takes in the value from an RTC module attached to the kit)

Thus, a simple loop like the following might not work:

```cpp
void loop(){
if (Serial.available()) {
    light(Serial.read() – ‘0’);
}
delay(500);
}
```

So my question is how can I add functionality such that the Arduino is constantly listening to the Serial port for instructions?

If you are interested in the potential things I want to be able to do with this functionality, please refer to this code: [Potentiall Additions](https://github.com/gilgameshskytrooper/NixeTubesShieldNCS314/raw/master/addedCode.cpp)

Thank you

Comment: (1) You already have serial initialization (Serial.begin(115200)) at your code. (2) "Now i doubt this alone.... ", "... simple loop like this might not work", why not try it first, and tell the error instead of using imagination